# Following mySQL table search result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following system where users can follow each other and search for users to follow. Here are examples of the **users** and **following** tables:

```
Users Table:
+-------+-----------+
| id    | userName  |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | John      |
| 2     | Harriet   |
| 3     | Chris     | 
| 4     | Lisa      | 
| 5     | Joe       | 
+-------+-----------+

Following Table:
+-------+-------+-------+
| id    | id_1  | id_2  |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     | 5     | 3     |
| 2     | 1     | 2     |
| 3     | 1     | 5     |
| 4     | 5     | 4     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to know how to structure a mySQL statement to join the **following** table with the **users** table where the username is like '%$search%' to return all results of this occurrence (i.e. searching *'jo'* returns John and Joe) and when there are multiple results for each person (i.e. Joe will occur twice in **Following**) return only results where id_1 is the current logged in users id to show that the logged in user is already following this person.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$qry = "
SELECT u.id
     , u.userName
     , f.id_1
     , f.id_2 
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN following f
    ON IF('$userid' = f.id_1, u.id = f.id_2, u.id = f.id_1)
 WHERE u.userName LIKE '%$search%';
 ";
```

This query returns every occurrence of the username in the **following** table but it should only return once.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not absolutely sure but give it a try

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.userName
     , f.id_1
     , f.id_2 
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN following f
  ON u.id in (f.id_1,f.id_2)
  AND f.id_1 = '$userid'
 WHERE u.userName LIKE '%$search%'
 ORDER BY u.id
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That works perfect. I had to get rid of the LIMIT 1 to return all search results. Thanks